# Is it possible to condense overlapping replacements?

Tags: php, regex

This code reformats a json string in three cycles (using three regular expressions):

```
preg_replace (
    array ( '/([^"{]+?),/', '/([^"{ ]+?)}"/', '/"{"/'),
    array ( '"$1", ', '"$1"]', '["' ),
    '{"fruits" : "{lemon,banana,apple}"}');

result: {"fruits" : ["lemon", "banana", "apple"]}
```

Is it possible to do the same in one cycle (not necessarily in PHP)?

The question is rather theoretical. I would like to know, if there is a method to do it just in one replacement.

Comment: What is the original task? Why json formatting maters?

Comment: Json doesn't matter. It is just an example.

Comment: it's not clear then. At this moment it looks like something no one should ever do.

Comment: That's why the question is: "Is it possible..."

Comment: no, not because that. Provide an example that explains what you need clearly. From the current description it is not obvious what and why you need to do.

Comment: I don't think that to be possible. You are introducing new characters and require different replacements. Regex works with one kind of replacement at a time (at least, for now).

Comment: Thank you. I needed a regex expert's opinion and I've got one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do that in regex directly.

But you can do that with a callback function:

```
preg_replace_callback(
    '/((?:"{|,)[^,}]+(?:}")?)/',
    function ($match) {
        if(substr($match[0],0,2) == '"{')
        { #first array element
            $ret = '["'.substr($match[0],2).'"';
        }elseif (substr($match[0], strlen($match[0])-2, 2) == '}"')
        { #last array element
            $ret = ', "'.substr($match[0],1,strlen($match[0])-3).'"]';
        }else{ #middle
            $ret = ', "'.substr($match[0],1).'"';
        }
        return $ret;
    },
    '{"fruits" : "{lemon,banana,apple}"}'
);
```

Result: `{"fruits" : ["lemon", "banana", "apple"]}`